# Printer not working

Tags: printing, printer, hardware-failure

I just got this Epson L3151 printer and I don't know how to set it up. I tried to print some document but the pages are coming out blank. The ink is somehow running out anyway. What should I do? Also when I start it, it makes loud noises.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there no manual?

Comment: I read the manual but it doesn't say anything about ink running out while is it is not printing pages so I thought I'd ask if anyone knew

Comment: So you followed these [steps](https://files.support.epson.com/docid/cpd5/cpd55460.pdf)?

Comment: Ink jet printers have sprayer jets.  When the printer is not printing, these jets are covered with a piece of rubber but it only slows the process of the jet drying out and clogging the exit.  If the printer has sat for to long, you might need to replace the ink.  If you are savvy.. you can pull the ink cartridges out and ***try*** to clean the jets yourself with hot water on a paper towel.  You will know you got it cleared because the ink will start flowing onto the paper towel as you wipe.  I used to write ink jet drivers.. I have done this many times.

Comment: Oh.. one more thing, this can be confirmed by doing a "nozzle check" using the menu built into the printer.  If that isn't printing, then your jets are clogged.

Comment: Note that an inkjet uses ink every time it starts up, even if it's not printing. Just switching it on/off repeatedly will eventually make it run out of ink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Epson software is available from this
[download page](https://www.epson.eu/support?productID=22934&language=en#product_search).

Click the blue "DOWNLOAD" button to download and install the software.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you!